# Is programming in layers real?

Tags: web-deployment, product, layer

I am fairly new in product development and I am trying to work over a product. The problem that I have realized is that people draw diagrams and charts showing different modules and layers.

But as I am working alone (I am my own team) I got a bit confused about the interaction I am facing in the development within the programs and I am wondering whether developing a product in modules is real or not?

Maybe I am not a great programmer, but I see no boundaries when data start to travel from frontend to backend.

Comment: This might be a good article to read. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159277/when-to-use-the-3-layers-model

Answer (score 1):

I've written a lot of layered applications and it can be a useful pattern but it can lead you astray too, and thinking in modules is a bit more useful.

One problem with layers is that they're often used as a reason for repackaging data as it flows through the system, when the data is packaged perfectly well when it enters the system, such as from a database.

Another issue is that layering by its very nature stacks modules on top of one another - this is just too naive for most systems.

I suggest you get a good book on design patterns and spend some time studying and understanding the trade-offs with different architectural approaches. Developing modular applications is not easy but it's worth taking the time to do it well.

Comment: Thanks @Ian . . . your answer is well appriciated